# Transfer learning for regression problems

Tags: regression, machine-learning, feature-selection, transfer-learning, pre-training

I have trained a regression model with 7 features for a given problem.
Now, I have another regression problem (quite similar to the previous one) where I have only 6 samples in hand, but with 3 more features than the first model (7+3). The correlation between the target value and these 3 additional features is very high.
So I would like to use transfer learning method to create a new model based on the old model; but I can not find a way to integrate the additional features into the model, since the old one was trained only on X features. On the other hand I must employ the 3 additional features in the new model which means that I cannot just remove or ignore them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way: Use your old model's prediction as a new feature and combine with the additional three you have, i.e. a four-length feature vector for each sample. Then, train with these new features. So, the old model will act like a static feature generator for you. Of course, you may have challenges with that low number of samples.

Comment: the reason of which I've turned to transfer learning is the issue of few samples of the second problem. with your proposed solution I think that I will encounter the same challenge

Comment: If you are going to train & modify a transferred model, even there is no additional features, you need a data volume. Otherwise, you'll end up using the transferred model as is. e.g. I can't imagine continuing training Inception with a few images.

Comment: @jojo with only 6 samples and 3 new features you are at very high risk of overfitting, getting a model that maybe works OK on those samples but doesn't generalize well. The suggestion in this answer (+1) might be the best you can do without getting more data.